# toggle button changed its state when scrolled in listview in android

Tags: android, listview, state, togglebutton

I have created listview with two textfield and one toggle button.i am able to get text from the listview when put toggle button on,but problem is when i close my application or i scroll the listview my toggle button state is changed.

the below is my full code :

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   ArrayList<String> call_log_no;
   ArrayList<String> call_log_name;

    String strStatus = "";
   //Array of booleans to store toggle button status

   public boolean[] status;
    StringBuffer sb;
   String phNum,cname,details;
   MatrixCursor mMatrixCursor;
   ArrayList<String> choiceList;
   ListView lvCountries;
   HashMap<String,Object> hm;
  int pos;

 // Each row in the list stores country name and its status
List<HashMap<String,Object>> aList 
 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>      ();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

  /** Restore from the previous state if exists */
 if(savedInstanceState!=null){
  status = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray("status");
 }



  call_log_no = new ArrayList<String>();
  call_log_name = new ArrayList<String>();
  choiceList = new ArrayList<String>();



  lvCountries = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);


 OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> 
  lv, View item, int position, long id) {

      ListView lView = (ListView) lv;

      SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) lView.getAdapter();

      HashMap<String,Object> hm = (HashMap) adapter.getItem(position);

      /** The clicked Item in the ListView */
      RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) item;

      /** Getting the toggle button corresponding to the clicked item */
     ToggleButton tgl = (ToggleButton) rLayout.getChildAt(0);


      String strStatus = "";
      if(tgl.isChecked()){
          tgl.setChecked(false);
          strStatus = "Off";
          status[position]=false;
      }else{
          tgl.setChecked(true);
          strStatus = "On";
          status[position]=true;
      }
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), (String) hm.get("no") + " : " +    strStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  };

  lvCountries.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

     // Each row in the list stores country name and its status
  List<HashMap<String,Object>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();


// The contacts from the contacts content provider is stored in this cursor
 mMatrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id","name","details"} );




  getCallDetails();

 //Creating an AsyncTask object to retrieve and load listview with contacts
ListViewContactsLoader listViewContactsLoader = new ListViewContactsLoader();

 // Starting the AsyncTask process to retrieve and load listview with contacts
 listViewContactsLoader.execute();

 }

/** An AsyncTask class to retrieve and load listview with contacts */
 private class ListViewContactsLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor>{

 @Override
 protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
     Uri contactsUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

     // Querying the table ContactsContract.Contacts to retrieve all the contacts
     Cursor contactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(contactsUri, null, null, null,
     ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");

     if(contactsCursor.moveToFirst()){
         do{
             long contactId = contactsCursor.getLong(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex("_ID"));

             Uri dataUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

             // Querying the table ContactsContract.Data to retrieve individual items like
             // home phone, mobile phone, work email etc corresponding to each contact
             Cursor dataCursor = getContentResolver().query(dataUri, null,
                                 ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId,
                                 null, null);

             String displayName="";

             String homePhone="";
             String mobilePhone="";
             String workPhone="";

             if(dataCursor.moveToFirst()){
                 // Getting Display Name
                 displayName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME ));
                 do{

                     // Getting NickName

                  // Getting Phone numbers
                     if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                         switch(dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data2"))){
                             case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME :
                                 homePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                 boolean isStringExists = (call_log_no.contains(homePhone)||(call_log_no.contains("+91"+homePhone)));
                                 if(isStringExists==true)
                                 {

                                 }

                                 else{
                                     call_log_no.add(homePhone);
                                     call_log_name.add(displayName);

                                 }

                                 break;
                             case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE :
                                 mobilePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));

                                 mobilePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                 boolean isStringE = (call_log_no.contains(mobilePhone)||(call_log_no.contains("+91"+mobilePhone)));
                                 if(isStringE==true)
                                 {

                                 }

                                 else{
                                     call_log_no.add(mobilePhone);
                                     call_log_name.add(displayName);

                                 }

                                 break;
                             case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK :
                                 workPhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                 boolean isStringExis = (call_log_no.contains(workPhone)||(call_log_no.contains("+91"+workPhone)));
                                 if(isStringExis==true)
                                 {

                                 }

                                 else{
                                     call_log_no.add(workPhone);
                                     call_log_name.add(displayName);

                                 }
                                 break;
                         }
                     }








                 }while(dataCursor.moveToNext());
                 String details = "";


                 // Adding id, display name, path to photo and other details to cursor
                 mMatrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{ Long.toString(contactId),displayName,details});
             }
         }while(contactsCursor.moveToNext());
     }
     return mMatrixCursor;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
     status = new boolean[call_log_name.size()];

    for(int i = 0,j = 0,k=0; i < call_log_name.size() ; i++,j++,k++)
      {
          HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String,Object>();
          status[k]=false;
        // choiceList.add("\nName: "+call_log_name.get(i)+"\nPhone Number: " + call_log_no.get(j));
         hm.put("no", call_log_no.get(i));
         hm.put("txt", call_log_name.get(j));
         hm.put("stat",status[k]);
         aList.add(hm);


      }


     // Keys used in Hashmap
     String[] from = {"txt","no","stat" };

     // Ids of views in listview_layout
     int[] to = {R.id.tv_item,R.id.tv_no, R.id.tgl_status};

     // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
     // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
     SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.activity_main, from, to);



     lvCountries.setAdapter(adapter);

 }
```

}

please help me.. and i want to save the all toggle button state and the text corresponding to the data

Comment: Have you used `ViewHolder`for it?

Comment: no i didn't use view holder, i don't know how to use that.

Comment: `Viewholder` is used to hold your objects and avoid to duplication of values in list items while scrolling and for that you need to make View Holder class in your `getView()` method.  For your solution check this link http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php in this the checkbox are. You need to maintain state for your togglebutton.

Comment: i am not using adapter class, and if i use getview() in activity class it is giving error

Comment: You can't use in Activity class. for that you need to make custom adapter class.

Comment: why custom adapter class is use for ?

Comment: To handle state position for toggle button.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to approach the listview as follows.

1. Create a class to hold the listview data. for example :

   public class Countries{

   private String mName;
   private boolean mChecked;

   public Countries{
   }

   public String getName(){
       return mName;
   }

   public void setName(String name){
       mName = name;
   }

   public boolean isChecked(){
       return mChecked;
   }

   public void setChecked(boolean checked){

   ```
   mChecked = checked;
   ```

   }

}

2. Create a custom array adapter for the listview.

public class CountriesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
public CountriesListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Countries>countriesList) {
    super(context, resource, countriesList);    

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View cell, ViewGroup parent) {

    //Get an instance of our cell holder                                                                         
    Holder holder;

    //If this is the first time the Listview is going to display this cell
    //Create new Holder
    if(cell == null)
    {   

        Holder = new Holder();

        //Get layout inflater service to inject our view in the listview cell
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);          
        cell = vi.inflate(R.layout.your_xml_layout, parent, false);

        holder.textView = (TextView)cell.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        holder.toggleButton = (ToggleButton)cell.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

        //Attach the new cell to the listview row
        cell.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        //The row was already created before to get it from the row
        holder = (Holder)cell.getTag();
    }

    //Get item at current position
    Countries country = getItem(position);

    //Set row data
    holder.textview.setText(country.getName());
    holder.toggleButton.setChecked(country.isChecked());

    //return the cell to the listview to dosplay
    return cell;

}

//this holder class will be filled from the layout xml and attached 
//to the row as a tag object
private class Holder{
    TextView textView;
    ToggleButton  toggleButton;
}
```

}

3. After your create a new array of countries items in your activity or fragment.
4. Then initiate a new adapter pass the countries list.
5. set adapter to the listview.
6. now on the click listener you get the Country object at the given position.

With this method you can scroll and the toggled button remained toggled.

Comment: I have two arraylist ,how to put their arraylist item in the listview by using above method?

Comment: What do u mean by 2 arraylist?

Comment: ArrayList<String> call_log_no;
 ArrayList<String> call_log_name;                                                                     i am setting value from the above  arraylist to the listview.

Comment: dont use and array list for 2 objects...but create an object which holds all the data..see my example I created a class to hold that..Then cretae an arraylist of your object like so ..ArrayList<MyObject>

Comment: i will be taking data from database so how i can populate that data to the listview using the above method which you told?

Comment: You create a new Java class with all properties needed..you populate the class with data from server...you create array list of your class..you pass the array list to the adapter...you set the adapter to the listview